# I'm having some errors with GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I'm having some errors in making a calculator program , I've tried many things but nothing works , my errors are.

1. When you click any number button it continues with the default value zero ("0 is my default text for the calculator")
2. When you insert a number in the calculator and if the text field has an old answer ,  the number you pressed will add to the answer that you had gotten.

Please help!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Calculator extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    // ***************** VARIABLES ********************************************
    private GridBagLayout layout;
    private GridBagConstraints gbc;

    private JButton [] numberButtons;
    private JButton [] otherButtons;

    private JTextField field;

    private double num1, num2, total;
    private int operator;

    // ***************** ORDERING BUTTONS ***************************************
    // [0]=gridx(column), [1]=gridy(row), [2]=gridwidth, [3]=gridheight

    // Number buttons
    private int [] [] numConstraints = new int [] [] {
        {0, 5, 2, 1}, // 0
        {0, 4, 1, 1}, // 1
        {1, 4, 1, 1}, // 2
        {2, 4, 1, 1}, // 3
        {0, 3, 1, 1}, // 4
        {1, 3, 1, 1}, // 5
        {2, 3, 1, 1}, // 6
        {0, 2, 1, 1}, // 7
        {1, 2, 1, 1}, // 8
        {2, 2, 1, 1}, // 9
    };

    // [0]=gridx(column), [1]=gridy(row), [2]=gridwidth, [3]=gridheight
    // Other buttons
    private int [] [] otherConstraints = new int [] [] {
        {2, 5, 1, 1}, // .
        {4, 4, 1, 2}, // =
        {3, 5, 1, 1}, // +
        {3, 4, 1, 1}, // -
        {3, 3, 1, 1}, // *
        {3, 2, 1, 1}, // '/'
        {2, 1, 1, 1}, // +/-
        {1, 1, 1, 1}, // C
        {4, 2, 1, 1}, // %
        {4, 1, 1, 1}, // ?
        {3, 1, 1, 1}, // ^2
        {0, 1, 1, 1}, // ?
        {4, 3, 1, 1}, // 1/x
    };

    // ***************** CONSTRUCTORS
    // *******************************************
    public Calculator() {

        // Define Layout
        layout = new GridBagLayout();
        layout.columnWidths = new int [] {60, 60, 60, 60, 60}; // 5 button columns and size
        layout.rowHeights = new int [] {60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60}; // 6 button rows and size
        setLayout(layout);

        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        // Number Buttons display
        numberButtons = new JButton [10];

        for (int i = 0 ; i < numberButtons.length ; i++) {
            numberButtons[i] = new JButton("" + i);
            numberButtons[i].addActionListener(this); // allow button to be listened

            gbc.gridx = numConstraints[i][0]; // column **ALL THESE ALREADY
                                              // DEFINED ABOVE**
            gbc.gridy = numConstraints[i][1]; // row
            gbc.gridwidth = numConstraints[i][2]; // width
            gbc.gridheight = numConstraints[i][3]; // height
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH; // Take complete cell space
            gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2); // padding

            add(numberButtons[i], gbc); // add the buttons
        }

        // Other Butttons incl. operators
        otherButtons = new JButton [13];
        otherButtons[0] = new JButton(".");
        otherButtons[1] = new JButton("=");
        otherButtons[2] = new JButton("+");
        otherButtons[3] = new JButton("-");
        otherButtons[4] = new JButton("x");
        otherButtons[5] = new JButton("Ã·");
        otherButtons[6] = new JButton("Â±");
        otherButtons[7] = new JButton("C");
        otherButtons[8] = new JButton("%");
        otherButtons[9] = new JButton("?");
        otherButtons[10] = new JButton("^2");
        otherButtons[11] = new JButton("?");
        otherButtons[12] = new JButton("1/x");

        for (int i = 0 ; i < otherButtons.length ; i++) {
            gbc.gridx = otherConstraints[i][0];
            gbc.gridy = otherConstraints[i][1];
            gbc.gridwidth = otherConstraints[i][2];
            gbc.gridheight = otherConstraints[i][3];

            otherButtons[i].addActionListener(this);

            add(otherButtons[i], gbc);

        }

        // Display text field
        field = new JTextField(); // define field
        field.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK)); // set border color to black
        field.setEditable(false); // cannot be edited
        field.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 26)); // font style and size
        field.setHorizontalAlignment(field.RIGHT);
        field.setText("0");
        gbc.gridx = 0; // column
        gbc.gridy = 0; // row
        gbc.gridwidth = 5; // width
        gbc.gridheight = 1; // height

        add(field, gbc); // add the field

    }

    // Action Events for each button
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { // e can be any name

        // for number buttons pressed, display to the field
        for (int i = 0 ; i < numberButtons.length ; i++) {
            if (e.getSource() == numberButtons[i]) {
                field.setText(field.getText() + i); // settext=set to field, gettext=get pressed key from i
            }
        }

        if (e.getSource() == otherButtons[0] && !field.getText().contains(".")) { // if current number is 0 and if decimal is
            field.setText(field.getText() + "."); // already added, another decimal cannot be added
        }

        if (e.getSource() == otherButtons[6]) { // 6 is +/- (change vslue to positive or negative)
            field.setText("" + (-1 * Integer.parseInt(field.getText()))); // multiply by negative 1 to change value
        }

        if (e.getSource() == otherButtons[7]) { // 7 is C (clear)
            field.setText("0"); // if pressed clear everything
        }

        if (e.getSource() == otherButtons[2]) { // 2 is +
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(field.getText());
            operator = 2;
            field.setText("");
        }

        if (e.getSource() == otherButtons[3]) { // 3 is -
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(field.getText());
            operator = 3;
            field.setText("");
        }

        if (e.getSource() == otherButtons[4]) { // 4 is *
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(field.getText());
            operator = 4;
            field.setText("");
        }

        if (e.getSource() == otherButtons[5]) { // 5 is /
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(field.getText());
            operator = 5;
            field.setText("");
        }

        if (e.getSource() == otherButtons[10]) { // 10 is ^2
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(field.getText());
            field.setText("" + (num1 * num1));
        }

        if (e.getSource() == otherButtons[12]) { // 12 is 1/x
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(field.getText());
            field.setText("" + (1 / num1));
        }

        if (e.getSource() == otherButtons[9]) { // 9 is ?
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(field.getText());
            field.setText("" + (Math.sqrt(num1)));
        }

        if (e.getSource() == otherButtons[8]) { // 8 is %
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(field.getText());
            field.setText("");
            num2 = Integer.parseInt(field.getText());
            field.setText("" + num1 * (num2 / 100));
        }

        if (e.getSource() == otherButtons[1]) { // if = button pressed:
            num2 = Integer.parseInt(field.getText()); // set num2 to new entered number

            // if = is pressed and if:
            if (operator == 2) {
                total = num1 + num2;
            }
            else if (operator == 3) {
                total = num1 - num2;
            }
            else if (operator == 4) {
                total = num1 * num2;
            }
            else if (operator == 5) {
                total = num1 / num2;
            }

            else {
                field.setText("");
            }

            operator = 0; // if = is pressed but no operator inserted
            field.setText("" + total); // display result

        }

    }

    // ***************** MAIN METHOD
    // ********************************************
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculator");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(new Calculator(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        // frame.setSize(320, 400); //width, height

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code?

Comment: use a boolean to determine when the input field need to be cleared upen cliking another button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`total` should be a local variable initialized to 0, before the `if` statements calculating the total.

For clearing the total

```
private boolean clearOnKeyPress = false;

    double total = 0;
    if ...
    clearOnKeyPress = true;
    operator = 0;
    field.setText("" + total); //display result
```

For not appending to 0:

```
    if (e.getSource() == numberButtons[i]) {
        if (clearOnKeyPress || field.getText().equals("0")) {
            field.setText(""):
            clearOnKeyPress = false;
        }
        field.setText(field.getText() + i);
    }
```

Another way, without boolean flag, would be to use `field.selectAll()' selecting the entire total, and`field.cut()` on a number press, removing any selection.

Comment: It fixed the first error , but the second one still remains

Comment: The second error resolved using a boolean flag `clearOnKeyPress`.